# Push doesn't work (Error: Could not get)

Tags: ios, cordova, ratchet, ratchet-2, push.js

Trying to use Ratchet's push.js, but doesn't work.
What I have in console:

```
[Error] Error: Could not get: file:///var/mobile/Applications/337585D8-89E1-4810-AB37-0A6DD2DA3A34/Gustav.app/www/booking.html
failure (ratchet.js, line 446)
onreadystatechange (ratchet.js, line 371)
```

If you will tap link like ten times you start to receive this:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'cacheMapping[PUSH.id].url')
cachePush (ratchet.js, line 202)
PUSH (ratchet.js, line 392)
touchend (ratchet.js, line 258)
```

All this console data from real device tests (iOS 7.1), wrapper is Cordova CLI 3.4.1-0.1.0.

File booking.html exist, native safari failure like this

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (menu.html, line 0)
```

doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push.js` does not support file:// protocol.

> Ratchet uses XHR requests to fetch additional pages inside the
>   application. Due to security concerns, modern browsers prevent XHR
>   requests when opening files locally (aka using the file:// protocol);
>   consequently, Ratchet does not work when opened directly as a file. A
>   common solution to this is to simply serve the files from a local
>   server. One convenient way to achieve this is to run python -m
>   SimpleHTTPServer  to serve up the files in the current directory
>   to `http://localhost:<port>`

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/488) and [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/issues/553) submitted on Github

It seems like this is a common issue with using Cordova and Ratchet.

Comment: Thanks! Here is link(https://github.com/artemave/ratchet/commit/5ccfdd765ecd15666b83b0b9abc15e4c120b7713) to commit that adding file:// support in ratchet, by the way.

Comment: @lenyapugachev hm doesn't really make any sense to use ratchet with Cordova then if file p. can't be used. Do you know when file:// will be supported?

Comment: The ajax request succeeds but returns a status code of 0 for iOS 7.1. Allowing failed status `xhr.status === 0 (line 383 : ratchet.js)` allows page transitions when installed on a device.